# Running tflite sample segmentation app with different model

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to run the sample app from [tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_segmentation/android) for image segmentation with a different model.
I would like to run it with the model [shufflenetv2](https://github.com/sercant/android-segmentation-app/tree/master/app/src/main/assets) with dpc.
So I copied the model, and changed `imageSize` to `225` in `ImageSegmentationModelExecutor.kt`.
Then I am getting the error

> something went wrong: y + height must be <= bitmap.height()

Doing some small adjustments in the function scaleBitmapAndKeepRatio of ImageUtils.kt solves the problem. (Just changed targetBmp.width to height twice, once in the matrix and 2nd time in the return.)
This brings the next error

> something went wrong: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer with 202500 bytes and a Java Buffer with 4252500 bytes.

The ratio of these 2 numbers is the NUM_CLASSES. Not sure if this is the right way to get it running or how to continue from here.
Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two unrelated problems

**1) The method [scaleBitmapAndKeepRatio](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_segmentation/android/lib_utils/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/imagesegmentation/utils/ImageUtils.kt) seems buggy.**

By replacing `width` with `height` you're not solving the problem. Only changing the moment when it will happen. See the reference for [createBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap#createBitmap)

> if the x, y, width, height values are outside of the dimensions of the source bitmap, or width is <= 0, or height is <= 0, or if the source bitmap has already been recycled

so to get a squared adjusted bitmap, you'd be better off by getting the smallest dimension like this

```
val dimension = min(targetBmp.height, targetBmp.width)
```

and replacing `width` with `dimension`

**2) I believe the input node of your tflite model is not compatible with tflite segmentation example**

Have a look to the [default model Google provides](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/deeplabv3/1/metadata/2?lite-format=tflite) with [Netron](https://netron.app/)

You can see the the default model input node is a quantized `float32` To me, it seems likely that you've converted your model to tflite using the default instructions in [quantize.md](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/quantize.md). This will get you a model expecting a quantized `uint8` input node, and so, the datatype is a mismatch. Remember tflite examples in the repository are taylor-made for an specific input and not very generic.

You'd rather do the conversion shown below to get as input node a quantized `float32`

```
# Load the TensorFlow model
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
    graph_def_file = MODEL_FILE, 
    input_arrays = ['sub_2'], # For the Xception model it needs to be `sub_7`, for MobileNet it would be `sub_2`
    output_arrays = ['ResizeBilinear_2'], # For the Xception model it needs to be `ResizeBilinear_3`, for MobileNet it would be `ResizeBilinear_2`
    input_shapes={'sub_2':[1,257,257,3]}
)
```